# The Short Brother

Tags: riddle

> I work as hard as my brothers do
>   Outcast, though I am
>   I am short and stubby, too
>   They are lean and tan
>   
>   My cousin has the same affliction
>   His kin look down on him
>   We suffer, us, this poor condition
>   Though it may seem grim
>   
>   He and I are strong and hardy
>   Strongest of the lot
>   Critical to work are we
>   Even though we're squat
>   
>   Try to work without us and
>   You'll find it most unpleasant
>   You may be need a helping hand
>   If we are not present
>   
>   There are those that we relate to
>   Somewhere south they prowl
>   From dealing with them we eschew
>   For they smell most foul
>   
>   If I am lost you can replace
>   Me with one of them
>   I would suggest, though, in his place
>   You use one of his kin
>   
>   Now, who am I that moves so free
>   And who are my brothers?
>   Who's my cousin and where is he?
>   To the south, who are the others?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> You are the thumb.

which is short ad stubby but has greater freedom of movement compared to the brothers

> the fingers

who are lean and tall but not as strong.

The cousin I guess is the

> thumb on the other hand

Finally down south are

> the smelly toes. It appears that you can surgically replace a missing thumb with a big toe which is pretty crazy stuff.

Comment: Well done. I was deliberate about not being too cryptic but I guess it could have used a little more mystery than I gave it. This is close enough to exactly right so you get the tick. You'll get the +1, too, if you can be more specific about those to the south. Stanza 6 indicates that it should be a particular digit.

Comment: If you had made it any more cryptic I probably wouldn't have got it. Riddles are not really my strength.